# How do I use my complex ViewModel in my View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a newbie to .Net MVC and I am struggling to solve the following.

I have my Model which contains two tables I wish to display on one page. The tables are Products and Suppliers.

I have created a ViewModel which contains both of the enumerated table.

In the Controller I have created a List object which contains the data.

The problem I have is that define the fields in the View i.e. Only **item.Product** is available when I need **item.Product.ID**

Please see my code below:

**Product.cs** - Generated by Entity Framework

```
namespace MyApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.Suppliers = new HashSet<Supplier>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Supplier.cs** - Generated by Entity Framework

```
namespace MyApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Supplier
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ProductWithSupplier.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class ProductWithSupplier
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var p = from product in _db.Products
                        select product;

        var s = from supplier in _db.Suppliers
                        select supplier;

        var model = new List<MyApp.ProductWithSupplier> { new ProductWithSupplier()
            {
                Products = p,
                Suppliers = s
            }
        };

        return View(model);
}
```

**Index.cshtml** - This is where the problem is. I can't specify Product.ID, Product.title, Product.img, Product.price and Supplier.name

```
@model List<MyApp.ProductWithSupplier>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

        @foreach (var item in Model) {

        <div class="product @Html.Raw(item.Products.size)">
            <div class="media">
                <a href="product.html" title="product title">
                    <img src="@Html.Raw(item.Products.img)" alt="product title" data-img="product-1" />
                </a>            
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <p class="name"><a href="product.html">@Html.Raw(item.Products.title)</a></p>
                <p class="price"><span class="cur">&pound;</span><span class="total">@Html.Raw(item.Products.price)</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="details-supplier" id="details-@Html.Raw(item.Products.ID)">
                @foreach (var supplier in Model) {
                    <p>@supplier.Suppliers.name</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should be using `@foreach (var item in Model.Products) { ...  }` because Products and Suppliers are IEnumerable<> if I am correct.

Comment: Are you retrieving the single data which contains the list or you have list of data. If case 1st is applied, then remove the enumerable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define two `IEnumerable`s in ProductWithSupplier, so when you iterate through your `List<ProductWithSupplier>` you have each `item` of type `ProductWithSupplier` that contains two enumerables, you can't use `item.Products.title` because `item.Products` is of type `IEnumerable<Product>`.

What you should do is put one more `foreach` inside your first one, check for the supplier.ProductID, add types instead of `var`, and so on like so:

```
@model List<MyApp.ProductWithSupplier>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

    @foreach (MyApp.ProductWithSupplier item in Model)
    {
        @foreach (Product product in item.Products)
        {
          <div class="product @Html.Raw(item.Products.size)">
            <div class="media">
              <a href="product.html" title="product title">
                <img src="@Html.Raw(item.Products.img)" alt="product title" data-img="product-1" />
              </a>            
            </div>
            <div class="details">
              <p class="name"><a href="product.html">@Html.Raw(item.Products.title)</a></p>
              <p class="price"><span class="cur">&pound;</span><span class="total">@Html.Raw(item.Products.price)</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="details-supplier" id="details-@Html.Raw(item.Products.ID)">
            @foreach (Supplier supplier in item.Suppliers)
            {
                @if (supplier.productID == product.ID)
                {
                  <p>@supplier.name</p>
                }
            }
            </div>
          </div>
        }
    }
```

If you want just one `Product`, change your `ProductWithSupplier` to remove `IEnumerable<>` around Product, and remove the second `foreach`, using directly `item.Product`.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer! Looking at the model being returned this seems logical but it's now complaining that it can't find the "Product" and "Supplier" namespace in the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks Eregrith! It worked a treat (almost).

A few amendments to the above:

1. Removed the @ on subsequent foreach statements. Syntax error.
2. Used "foreach (MyApp.Supplier supplier in item.Suppliers)"
3. @Html.Raw(item.Products.size) beccomes @Html.Raw(product.size)

Answer (score 0):

The model of the view is of type `List<MyApp.ProductWithSupplier>` but inside a single `ProductWithSupplier` you defined collections of `Product` and `Supplier`. I guess you want to use `ProductWithSupplier` as model for the view and iterate through both products and suppliers.

```
@model ProductWithSupplier
```

The ViewModel should contain a single Product with multiple suppliers to represent your data structure:

```
public class ProductWithSupplier // this should be ProductWithSuppliers I guess.
{
    public Product Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

You have to change the controller accordingly.

It's also possible to use `IEnumerable<Supplier>` as model for the view, iterate through them and use `Product` navigation property on a `Supplier` to get info about the product.

Answer (score 0):

use below thing i have not tried it though but same sceniro worked for me

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Supplier>
```

and u will be able to access the product.item , product.id etc

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products.id) // to access properties of products
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) // to access properties of suppliers
            </td>


        </tr>
}
```